# CalendarProvider : cursor always null

Tags: android, android-calendar

So I'm trying to get every event from today, from a specific calendar ID. I've encoutered no problem while writing, updating, and deleting events, but I cant' get reading to work.

Here's my code :

```
    String[] query= new String[]{
            Events.CALENDAR_ID,
            Events.TITLE,
            Events.DESCRIPTION,
            Events.DTSTART,
            Events.HAS_ATTENDEE_DATA,
            Attendees.ATTENDEE_NAME,
            Attendees.ATTENDEE_EMAIL
    };

    String selection = "(( " + Events.DTSTART + " >= " + today.getTime() + " ))";

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.READ_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return null;
    }
    Cursor cur = activity.getBaseContext().getContentResolver().query(Events.CONTENT_URI, query, selection, null, null);

    Log.d("CalendarUtility","is cursor null : "+Boolean.toString(cur==null)); // always prints true
```

I tried without minimum date, but my cursor is still null.
Just in case, since API updates changes everything :
`compileSdkVersion 25`, `minSdkVersion 21`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found why it wasn't working. My query tries to access `CalendarContract.Attendees` (with `Attendees.ATTENDEE_NAME` and `Attendees.ATTENDEE_EMAIL`), but my Cursor is meant to return the `CalendarContract.Events` table.

So here's what I did:

```
private static String[] EVENTS_QUERY = new String[]{
        Events._ID,
        Events.CALENDAR_ID,
        Events.TITLE,
        Events.DESCRIPTION,
        Events.DTSTART,
        Events.HAS_ATTENDEE_DATA
        // No Attendees columns
};

private static String EVENTS_SELECTION = "(( " + Events.DTSTART + " >= " + nowTimeInMillis + " ))";

//...


Cursor cur = activity.getContentResolver().query(Events.CONTENT_URI, EVENTS_QUERY, EVENTS_SELECTION, null, null);
```

And later, if my event has attendee data :

```
String[] ATTENDEES_QUERY = new String[]{
                                Attendees.EVENT_ID,
                                Attendees.ATTENDEE_NAME,
                                Attendees.ATTENDEE_EMAIL
                        };
String ATTENDEES_SELECTION =  "(( " + Attendees.EVENT_ID + " == " + eventId + " ))";
Cursor att = activity.getContentResolver().query(Attendees.CONTENT_URI,ATTENDEES_QUERY,ATTENDEES_SELECTION,null,null);
```